# Using PyGitHub to push file to GitHub with Python, getting a "Branch master not found" error

Tags: python, github, github-api, pygithub

I am trying to upload a .csv file to GitHub using this code:

```
### THIS PART WOKRS ###
g = Github("My_Access_Key")
repo = g.get_user().get_repo('tradr')
all_files = []
contents = repo.get_contents("")
while contents:
    file_content = contents.pop(0)
    if file_content.type == "dir":
        contents.extend(repo.get_contents(file_content.path))
    else:
        file = file_content
        all_files.append(str(file).replace('ContentFile(path="','').replace('")',''))
with open('./Data/PriceGrabber/PriceData.csv', 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
# Upload to github
git_prefix = 'tradr/'
git_file = git_prefix + 'PriceData.csv'
### THIS PART WORKS ###

### GET AN ERROR HERE BELOW ###
if git_file in all_files:
    contents = repo.get_contents(git_file)
    repo.update_file(contents.path, "committing files", content, contents.sha, branch="master")
    print(git_file + ' UPDATED')
else:
    repo.create_file(git_file, "committing files", content, branch="master")
    print(git_file + ' CREATED')
```

This is the error I get:

```
GithubException: 404 {"message": "Branch master not found", "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents"}
```

I would be fine using any method that might work better. Searching seems to say that this may be an authentication issues [1].

[1] https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/560

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
It worked after I changed the **branch='master'** by **branch='main'**.

That's because of that: https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-main-starting-next-month/

Cheers,